# doctrine orm: bypass lazy loading and prefetch related records in a getter

Tags: orm, frameworks, symfony1, doctrine

Working with Doctrine ORM, is it possible to enable auto eager loading of related records when using in a getter ? (without explicit leftJoins())

I know I can use a leftJoin() to obtain the object with related records, 
but I want to avoid creating a DQL query for every object and simply have
some kind of automatic "prefetching" of related records.

This is useful when you have to cycle through nested Doctrine_Records
and it's exactly the same functionality that Kohana ORM has through the with() statement:

http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm#with

(It simply executes the query with the joins even if you get only the 'root' record with the array syntax).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understood but you may find answer in [doctrine doc](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/ru/component-overview%3acollection%3aloading-related-records) :

```
$users->loadRelated('Phonenumbers');
```

Comment: This will not work for described scenario. First collection of users must be loaded (first sql query), after that loadRelated will load Phonenumbers for all loaded users (second sql query). Good to know this, but this is not the answer...